# where my '[]' is?, bash program

Tags: linux, bash, shell

in linux ,bash program.
I write this:

```
msg=`date  '+%m-%d %H:%M'`" alipay recharge [$sum] in past 15 mins"
echo $msg >> $MonitorLog
```

Mostly it works ,but sometime.the result will like this:

```
07-15 09:01 card recharge 0 in past 30 mins
```

My sentence changes. not 0, if $sum=0 ,it should be:

```
07-15 09:01 card recharge [0] in past 30 mins
```

I don't know where my '[]' is? can you help me ,thanks a lot.

Comment: try escaping your sq-brackets, ie. `...alipay recharge \[$sum\] ..`. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

You are hitting shell globbing. See the output below.

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 14 21:40 5
$ sum=10
$ msg=`date  '+%m-%d %H:%M'`" alipay recharge [$sum] in past 15 mins"
$ echo $msg
07-14 21:41 alipay recharge [10] in past 15 mins
$ sum=5
$ msg=`date  '+%m-%d %H:%M'`" alipay recharge [$sum] in past 15 mins"
$ echo $msg
07-14 21:41 alipay recharge 5 in past 15 mins
$ echo "$msg"
07-14 21:41 alipay recharge [5] in past 15 mins
```

Comment: @kojiro Actually, if you want to get technical this is `Pattern Matching` in the context of `Pathname expansion` (which is generally, and colloquially, called `globbing`). And since, in this case, this is in fact filename matching it is globbing in both the general and specific cases.

Answer (score 2):

[@Etan Reisinger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748657/45375) contains the crucial pointer:

**Shell expansions are inadvertently applied to `$msg`, because it is *unquoted***.

### tl;dr:

**Double-quote your variable references to protect them from interpretation by the shell**:

```
echo "$msg" >> "$MonitorLog"    # due to double-quoting, contents of $msg used as is
```

**Generally, the only reason NOT to double-quote a variable reference is the express intent to have the shell *interpret* the value (apply expansions to it)** - see below.

---

In the case at hand, here's what happens if you do not double-quote `$msg`:

After splitting the value of `$msg` into *words* by *whitespace* (word splitting), *pathname expansion* is applied to each:

I.e., each word that looks like a glob (a filename pattern), is matched against filenames - in the specified directory or, without a path component, in the current one - and if matches are found, *that word is replaced by matching filenames*.

A word such as `[0]` happens to be a valid glob (`[...]` encloses a *set* of matching characters; in this case, the set is made up of only 1 char., `0`), and if a file named `0` happens to be present in the current directory, `[0]` is *replaced by that matching filename*, `0` - effectively making the `[]` disappear  - this is what happened in the OP's case.
(See `man bash`, section `Pathname Expansion`, for what constitutes valid globs.)